# Execute imported sql file

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I am executing the following command in my Javascript file.
No tables and data is inserted till now.
If I write only 1 query at a time in the imported file then it works fine but when I want to execute all the queries present in the imported file "Chinook_Sqlite.sql" then it does not execute anything.

Kindly suggest me the way.Thank You..

```
   // Create sqlite database instance
   var sqlitedb = openDatabase("Chinook", "", "Chinook", ''); 
    // Import the sql file
    $.get("../Chinook_Sqlite.sql", function(content) {
       // Start Transaction
        sqlitedb.transaction(function (tx) { 
            // Start Execution 
            tx.executeSql(content);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check content variable before `tx.executeSql(content);` call? You call it asyncroniously, try to rewrite it to:

```
  // Create sqlite database instance
   var sqlitedb = openDatabase("Chinook", "", "Chinook", ''); 
    // Import the sql file
    $.get("../Chinook_Sqlite.sql", function(content) {
       var scriptContent = content;
       // Start Transaction
        sqlitedb.transaction(function (tx) { 
            // Start Execution 
            tx.executeSql(scriptContent);
        });
    });
```

Comment: when I have console.log(content) then it shows me right queries

Comment: Actually, as CL wrote, executeSql work only with single query. You just need parse your quieries line by line and exequte separately inside transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`executeSql` executes a single SQL statement.

You have to extract the SQL statements from your file and call `executeSql` for each of them.

Comment: I need to populate 10 lacs data in my DB.I cant extract it individually.Suggest me some way..

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: I have written in my current question that I know its not working on multiple queries..Its working on single query only and I need the way to implement it and I have not found the solution yet.